# SwiftUI List not rendering

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I'm trying to display a simple list of text like so:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var users = [UserModel]()
    ...
```

```
List(viewModel.users) { user in
    Text(user.name) //this line doesn't get executed
}
```

```
class UserModel: BaseMapperModel, Identifiable {
    var id: Int = -1
    var name: String = "Unknown"
}
```

When I break at the "List" line, I can see that viewModel.users has 2 objects:

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : <UserModel: 0x7f8e85ce8e10>
  ▿ 1 : <UserModel: 0x7f8e85ce9a10>
```

And when I `po viewModel.users[0].name`I see a valid name. So why isn't the text getting displayed? Why does the List line get executed, but the Text line does not? The users have unique ids.

Comment: This needs a [mre]. But, that being said, your `UserModel` has a static `id`, so it won't be able to identify different users. It should also probably be a `struct` and not a `class`. Step 1 would be to change `id` to `var id = UUID()`

Comment: Does List { ForEach(viewModel.users, id: \.id)} work?

Comment: My guess is that you somewhere have a sink on your users? or maybe you are still on the background thread? Or you collect the data twice? It can for sure be like you say that it have an value, but the moment after it might not have a value and reload the view.

Comment: make the `UserModel` a `struct` and make sure you list isn't inside a `ScrollView`

Comment: @jnpdx I can't make UserModel a struct. It inherits from another class. And the ids get set when I create instances.

Comment: I tried changing UserModel to a struct, and var id = UUID(). It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Like I said at first, this needs a [mre] — it’s all guesswork about what the mysterious part of your system here that isn’t included that is making a difference

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `List` doesn't work, but this does:

```
ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
    Text(user.name)
}
```